# Why this android project is not recognizing AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, android-studio, appcompatactivity

I am new to android programming and trying to build [this](https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/tree/student/Lesson04a-Starting-New-Activities/T04a.01-Exercise-AddNewActivity) android project in udacity's basic android course. But after updating to latest android studio bumblebee version, its starting to throws these errors:

- Cannot resolve symbol 'v7'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'.

The import statement is grayed out.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

My build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.explicitintent"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'

}
```

I have tried the following, but still it doesn't work:

- Clean Project
- Restart and Invalidated cache
- Deleted .idea folder and reopened project

But nothing seems to work so far. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try migrating to AndroidX

Comment: try to migrate your project into androidX or if you a newbie in android development then you can follow recent tutorial about android development. I think this project is backdated.

Comment: Yes but is there a way to resolve it without migrating to AndroidX.

Answer (score 1):

Migrate your project to androidx
Steps to do so :- **Refactor>Migrate to Androidx**
it will download the necessary files your error should be gone !!

Comment: Migrating to androidx and changing import statement to                                                     ```import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;``` still doesn't work.